# How to get vectorheads with the topend as T and the bottom end as arrowhead with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to produce vector heads in my plot with T head at the top end and arrowhead at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read gnuplot help

```
set arrow <tag> {nohead | head | backhead | heads}
                       {size <headlength>,<headangle>{,<backangle>}}
```

you would think it's easy, but I don't get the expected result neither with arrow 1 nor with arrow 2. I don't know what's wrong with this, maybe somebody can explain. A not so nice workaround would be to split the arrow in two arrows 3 and 4.

```
### different front- and backheads for arrows
reset session

set arrow 1 from -9,5 to -9,-5 heads size 1,45,90 
set arrow 2 from -6,5 to -6,-5 heads size 1,90,45

set arrow 3 from -3,5 to -3,0 backhead size 1,90
set arrow 4 from -3,0 to -3,-5 head size 1,45

set arrow 5 from 0,5 to 0,-5 heads size 1,45,90 empty
set arrow 6 from 2,5 to 2,-5 heads size 1,45,60 filled

x0=8; y0=5
x1=4; y1=-5
set arrow 7 from x0,y0 to x1,y1 backhead size 1,135
set arrow 8 from x0,y0 to x1,y1 head size 1,45

plot x
### end of code
```

**Edit:**

Actually, the description is a bit misleading: `backangle` is not the angle of the `backhead`, but the angle in the back of the head (see arrows 5 and 6).
And it looks like it is not forseen that an arrow has two *different* heads. Either it has no head, one in the front or one in the back or two identical ones on both sides. If you check [gnuplot arrow demo](http://www.gnuplot.info/demo/lines_arrows.html) you won't find arrows with different heads at front and back.

As workaround, maybe even easier than splitting an arrow (3 and 4), plot two arrows (7 and 8) on top of each other, one with a backhead and one with a (front)head.

Result:

[image]